# Why was this spam-flag declined (no evidence to support it)?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, spam

Just now, I reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098518/visual-basic-web-browser-uses-100-cpu) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098518/visual-basic-web-browser-uses-100-cpu) in the first posts review queue and I noticed the bold link to a website in the center and its name used multiple times in the post.

When reading the question I felt like the problem would be rather akward and it seemed like (more or less) clever way to spam a website with a link, so I flagged it as spam. Short after, I saw that my flag was declined with the reason: "*spam  declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it*".

Was my flag wrong? Why was it declined?

Comment: The better question is why do you think that is spam?

Comment: The post is removed. So maybe it was a spam anyway?

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt Right, I just noticed so too. It was actually removed for "reasons of moderation.". Maybe I was right after all? ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question was genuine and references to a page do not imply that the post exists for the sole reason to promote that link.

<sup>In fact, that's a pretty bad way to promote a link.</sup>

Comment: I do know that references are (of course) not just spam, but it seemed to be a very weird problem. But I guess you are right, probably not spam.. :)

Answer (score 8):

Spam flags have severe penalties for the poster (a substantial reputation loss), and therefore there's a pretty precise definition of "spam". The question you flagged in no way meets that definition, and the flag was appropriately declined. (Spam is defined as those posts you see advertising low cost footwear or dietary supplements or pretty girls available to marry from some country.) There's also no effort to self-promote in the question at all.