# Spam flag declined on spam post

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, spam

If [this post isn't spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025406/basic-affiliate-site) I'd eat my hat if they hadn't all been deleted after the Winter Bash, yet I got my spam flag declined. For the record, with the URL replaced:

> I want to build a site which sells products coming from affiliated shops (the transaction does not happen on my site). Before I jump into coding a more "complicated" site, is there an easy tool to build a simple MVP to test whether my idea has any potential? Imagine a site like this `http://spammy-url/womens-boots-all/category_252` with products only, where clicking on one of the pictures redirects you to another site (I re-iterate: the transaction does not actually happen on my site). I don't care about building search and categorisation at this time. All I'd want right now is to see whether there is a simple way (perhaps a template, which requires little coding) that allows me to 1) include few product links and 2) showcase the images of the products from these links so that they appear in a way similar to the link I shared `http://spammy-url/womens-boots-all/category_252`

Mentioning the same URL unnecessarily twice smells of naive blackhat SEO.

Note, I haven't actually visited the target site, but I've just had a quick Google and the URL can be found linked from pages looking like hijacked spam sites.

Comment: Doesn't look like a spam post to me.

Comment: It feels weird honestly.  It *might* be spam, but it *could* be a link to an example page.  I would reluctantly give them the benefit of the doubt on that one and think about opening the link in a VM later.

Comment: I like how one of the ["Related" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267591) here gives "those posts you see advertising low cost footwear" as an example of obvious spam.

Comment: The block of text with no line breaks is a dead giveaway.

Comment: @Knu more than enough of selfish-but-not-malicious questions are just singular blocks of text without any formatting.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We really need everyone to shift away from the "there's a link in this post - it must be spam" mindset. Because that's a horrible mindset to have. Not saying you should ignore it - let it raise some figurative flags in your mind that maybe you'd want to look at it closer. But reaching immediately for the spam button is not a good option.

To speak about this specific case:

- The user explicitly mentioned they were trying to build something over their own - they have a problem - and even said that the link was an example of what they were trying to do.
- The user has posted other questions in the past which haven't had any signs of spam-like behavior.

There's no reason to believe that this user had malicious intentions in providing this link. I'm sure I've provided my fair share of odd links in the past in an attempt to showcase something I was trying to achieve. Did I put much thought into how it would be received by my friends? Not really. Did they question why I was looking at that site in particular? Probably. Because I know there have been cases where I've wondered the same thing about links they've sent me.

**Is there a better way to portray what they're trying to show us?** Absolutely. They could have taken a screenshot of the page and uploaded a small snippet rather than linking to it directly. Or if they wanted to go the extra mile, made a neat drawing of the layout they were trying to achieve. But does that make this spam? Absolutely not. Linking to examples like that *does* make for a pretty bad question, though - and it was rightfully closed.

---

Also, for anyone who is afraid to click random links in posts out of fear for falling prey to the mischievous Internet dwellers, I encourage you to check out some spam of my own: [Web of Trust](https://www.mywot.com) - just type in a domain and you have an instant report on most sites which have been around for a while.

Comment: "mywot.com" UR WOT.COM M8?

Comment: Web of trust is nice, but how can I trust it when it gives such high rating to W3schools?

Comment: How do I decide whether to trust that installing Web of Trust browser extension is safe?

Comment: I don't think that is anyone's mindset. You are attacking a straw man here. And the implication is rather offensive. I would have flagged that as spam. I'd flag it all day long as spam. *It is spam.* You can sit here and argue about how users posting links is not spam, but that doesn't have anything to do with this question, which contains two clearly spam links. They are unsolicited links via an electronic system that advertise a site that sells products. That is the definition of spam. The lack of a spam history for the user just means they're not a spammer; it doesn't mean that post isn't.

Comment: We at Taverns recently observed a sudden increase on this kind of questions, and *I* personally think this is a new attempt to spam the site. While I agree that we should give benefit of the doubt, I still can't shift the mindset away due to the given observation.

Comment: @AndrewT. so, shall we just sit down, relax and watch the train wreck until it starts smoking, then pull out a "told ya" hat and report all the other small fires?