# Should this (partial) answer be an audit in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, low-quality-posts, specific-audit

This relates to a deleted spam/offensive answer to the question [*How to simulate key press event?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6138110/1364007).

Link to the specific review: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/23898621).

Screenshot of the answer (for non-10K users):
[image: For Java (not Javascript) you can not simulate keyclicks via the DOM. You need to simulate read windows clicks (see macro recorder tools like Autohotkey)]

This doesn't appear to be spam/offensive:

- The answer suggests (after other suggestions) AutoHotkey. There is the [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) tag which has 3000+ questions, so it's not like the user has suggested a dodgy piece of software/malware. The suggestion didn't come as a URL so it couldn't have been pointing to a malicious site, etc.
- The answer isn't gibberish and appears to be written as an honest attempt to answer the question. The OP responded to the answer as though it were a valid answer.
- The answer had a score of -1, suggesting that there weren't (m)any spam or rude/abusive flags on it.
- The answer was posted in May 2011 (one day after the question was posted, so not a late spam answer), and was not deleted until July 2019. The question itself has 5k views, so if it were actually spam or rude/abusive, presumably it would have received more flags in the eight years between it being posted and it being deleted.
- The answer isn't plagiarising another answer: looking at [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6138110/timeline) for the question, the first (non-deleted) answer was posted *after* the audit answer.

The only thing that I can think of for this to be correctly deleted as spam or rude/abusive is that the user posted the same answer to multiple questions in quick succession, but clearly there is no (easy) way that I can see this because the user has been deleted so I cannot click on their profile link.

I "passed" the audit by following the link on the post, noticing that the answer didn't appear, then clicking "Recommend Deletion" - but feel that this was probably cheating the system. In retrospect should have skipped (or failed) this audit.

If this is a bad audit, could it be made to not be an audit? Alternatively, if this is a good audit, could somebody explain to me why it was deleted?

---

Related(?):

- [Poor review audit labeling relevant answer as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319170/1364007)

Semi-related (but for audits containing links):

- [Review audit failure… and no, I don't understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337843/1364007)
- [Failed LQP audit: how to decide if an answer is spam?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367613/1364007)

Comment: I'm not sure why it was deleted as spam, but it's it a Java answer to a Javascript question?

Comment: Good point - I spotted, but forgot to mention, that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A side effect of a user getting deleted for spam is that all their negative-scored posts are also spam-deleted.

Unfortunately this particular answer was caught in this automatic action taken by the system. I have cleared the spam flags and re-deleted this answer so that it will no longer be eligible to be used as an audit.

Comment: Sam, discussing a similar recent complaint I discovered that system seems to be [broken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/397398/too-many-unfair-review-audits?noredirect=1#comment769799_397398) because audits were supposed to be posts less than 30 days old. Now mind you, I wouldn't object if this limitation was somewhat softened, especially if they wanted to use same system for some small sites which have much less traffic than SO, but allowing many years old posts as audits just feels wrong no matter what. 8 years old post as audit, that's just weird