# Review audit: Low quality answer seems acceptable for me

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

I failed the following review https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30949337 in the Low quality answers queue.

[image]

It seems like a fair attempt to answer the question and while not a perfect answer it does not deserve to be deleted in my opinion. Am I missing anything?

Comment: The answer was deleted as spam.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they advertised their book, their presentation, their paper, and their github repository. With JS code on a C++ question. Which was primarily looking for debugging help on that specific C++ code. That seems pretty spammy to me.

Comment: I don't have 10k reputation so can't see the audit, but I am ~95% certain based on the description that you've encountered a post by the same (deleted) user as I did in [Should this zero-score, not NAA, deleted answer be used as a Low quality answers audit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415519/1364007). Was it one of these audits? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy9RR.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvhaB.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7dbV.png)?

Comment: While the duplicate is about the same user, I feel the *specific* answer/audit is a much clearer case here. The answer has several red flags, with some being far from subtle.