# Weird audit in LQA

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I was reviewing the Low Quality Answers queue today when I was shown [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30964649). It's a detailed, thorough answer, with good formatting, so at first glance I can guess that it's probably not low quality. Looking a little closer, though, there are a few odd features: The question was asked over 10 years ago, while this answer is quite recent, and the answer begins by disputing the premise of the question - the question asks how to measure the entropy of a string, and how that relates to the string's quality, but the answer states that "the entropy of a string of English text does NOT signify quality" (and then provides examples, data, and code to support this argument).

I voted "Looks OK," and was immediately slapped with an audit failure. Apparently this post has already been "flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted by Community," which makes it automatically low-quality (and probably explains why it was chosen as an audit).

From my last question on Meta, I know that audits are procedurally chosen and don't always make sense, but this one makes even less sense than usual. Why was this seemingly reasonable post flagged as spam and deleted? Was it because it disagreed with the opinion expressed by the original question? Or did some automatic process delete the post because it was a new answer to a very old question and got downvoted?

EDIT: The linked duplicate answers my question, in that it explains why the post was flagged as spam (the user had been marked as a spammer and deleted), but I should note that in this case there were no visible "red flags" indicating that the answer might be spam. In the other case it was a suspicious post because the question was about C++ and the answer was given using JavaScript, but with this post the original question was very broad and not language-specific. When reviewing this question, I had no way of telling that the answer was spam, because the user has been deleted and I thus cannot see the context that they have posted the same "advertisement" answer on many other questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Review audit: Low quality answer seems acceptable for me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415721/review-audit-low-quality-answer-seems-acceptable-for-me), or the target of that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415519?

Comment: The audit system like to pick posts that are beyond a shadow of a doubt bad or good posts. unfortunately, the signals it uses to determine that are sometimes faulty.

Comment: I think when a user is destroyed as a spammer all their posts get marked as spam, even if some of them aren't necessarily spammy.

Comment: @cigien Yes, that's helpful! I had no idea the user posting that answer was actually trying to advertise his own textbook. Since the user account has been deleted, I couldn't see that the user was the author of the book or that the same user had posted spammy answers elsewhere.

Comment: This user posted the same thing 35 times. That's why it was deleted like that

Comment: That answer links to several repos on github from a user named gagniuc, references a book from a person named Gagniuc and links to Powerpoint presentation also about stuff from Gagniuc. This post isn't "loos ok" in my opinion, it is at least "looks weird" and maybe a bit like "looks like the person behind that answer is Gagniuc themself".