# Why does an irrelevant YouTube link inside an question not require a moderator's intervention?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged the question *[Why does the Modulo Operator not work as expected in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613863/why-does-the-modulo-operator-not-work-as-expected-in-kotlin)* as *in need of moderator intervention* and added:

> The link points to an YouTube video totally out of context

This is the link that the question contained (before it was edited and removed by another user):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EbnoElOJx0

My flag was declined!

I'm curious: isn't this a case for a moderator's intervention or do I get it wrong?

Comment: Why didn't you remove the link yourself?

Comment: @yivi Because I thought that removing the link is not enough. Can anyone promote their youtube videos like that?

Comment: If the post was solely SPAM, you should flag as SPAM (and not custom flag). If the post was not spammy, but only included an inappropriate link, better to fix it yourself directly, IMO.

Comment: Yes, maybe I should flag it as *spam*, so this is a case of wrong labeling of the flag, but is this a reason for the flag to be declined?

Comment: Use of a custom flag where a standard flag should be used is many times reason enough for flag declining. Since you do not share the decline reason, I can only guess that could happened there. Also, are you sure the question exists only to promote unsolicited advertising, and it's not a legitimate question with an ill-advised link?

Comment: The reason of decline I got: *flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*. My question is: isn't an unrelated or spam or out of context video link a reason for a moderator to apply a warning?

Comment: Relevant: [*Spam flag declined on spam post*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319148/2751851); [*Flag declined on spam answer*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371586/2751851)

Comment: No. If there is a clear pattern, maybe. But then you should probably make the mod aware of that pattern in your flag. A single instance of a stray link? The community (us) can deal with that. Only when we can't deal (reasonably) with something we invoke the diamond brigade.

Comment: @forpas: Note: spam is not "someone put a link to an unrelated Youtube video at the end of their otherwise valid post". The spam flag is for posts which are *entirely spam*.

Comment: Just FYI the link was removed by edit on [4th revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56613863/4) but then [edited-in again by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56613863/5)

Comment: There was no self-promotion or plagiarism here, @xdtTransform. Either of those would be valid reasons to flag for moderator attention. Do not try and handle those yourself; they require more action than a simple edit.

Comment: @CodyGray, exactly what I  mean. There is link that is an issue: Edit it. If it became an Edit War flag as such. If you found something weird call a mod and provide the information you have. No action other than edit is are promoted in my comment. By investigation I simply mean open the last 5 questions and  see if there is a pattern. I never try to handle thing, my greatest power is stronger than Thanos snap/ When I close this tab everyone disappear

Answer (score 19):

It was a moderator who removed the link. What else did you expect the moderators to do?

In general, removing some unrelated (and not offensive) link doesn't require moderator attention. Every user with >2k can remove it easily.

When the OP insists on keeping the link (by adding it again or by rolling back the removal), then a moderator should be involved. But in this case, you have to make that clear in the message.

Comment: I expected a warning from a moderator that they can't post irrelevant or spam videos and surely I did no expect the flag to be declined.

Comment: @forpas: I wouldn't call the video spam. It's not promoting anything, there is no indication that op is affiliated with that video. It's just there because of the "I am confusion" which I'd see as a funny way to enforce op's confusion. Sure, it should be removed, but it's not more spam than a "Please help me quick" text.

Comment: *It's not promoting anything* other than itself?

Comment: @forpas It's a meme. When the user has a pattern of such links, then you should maybe flag it, but then you have to state that very clear in the message. When it happens for the first time, then edit it out, and if you wish leave a comment explaining why you removed it. But no moderator needs to be involved. They have more than enough real problems on there agenda.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what a *meme* is supposed to mean. Anyway this question was asked by a new user who posted their 1st question. I think that this is exactly a case of a moderator to intervene so that the new user should be warned about future posts also.

Comment: Totally agree, I declined a similar flag and went to edit it and found a suggested edit removing the dead link from another user. It is something the flagger themselves could do.

Comment: Well, the link was added twice by OP. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56613863/2 https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56613863/5

Comment: @TadeuszKopec: True. But this has to be stated **in the flag**.

Comment: @forpas: [internet] memes are links to still images or video clips, often used to illustrate a point in a humourous way, and to be _memetic_ they generally have to gone "viral". [See more here](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/memes/).