# Moderator mistake -> Flagging impossible

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, retracted-flags

There is some question on Stack Overflow titled:

*[How to handle error logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940/how-to-handle-error-logging/30970#30970)*

The answer is simply:

**Try log4php, it is nice.**

Note that it has received 9 up-votes!. I flagged it as:

**Not an answer**

And some moderator **declined** my flag like this:

**declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it**

I am unable to flag more posts:

**Too many of your recent flags have been declined - please [review](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/5104596) them instead of flagging this post!**

[image]

When I go to review, I can just **view**, as there is no way to retract them (according to Meta question *[Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)*).

So, the questions are:

- Where are Stack Overflow standards?
- Why isn't it possible to retract my flags? (What is the meaning of review?)

Comment: I take issue with your suggestion that this is a moderator mistake. I don't see any reason for assuming it is.

Comment: That answer was posted the same month that SO started.  *Very* different standards back then, it took a while to discover what kind of Q+A works.  Retroactively changing the standards on existing posts, well, that only ever gets a lot of people upset.  Nobody enjoys having their contribution destroyed, not those 9 voters either.  Nor the hundreds of people that looked at it, took the advice and never found anything wrong with it.  Which does make it an answer.  What happened in 2008 needs to stay in 2008.

Comment: Retract means "cancel" **before** someone reviews it. So once the mod declined your flag, you could no longer retract it. You have to wait out the ban.

Comment: @HansPassant, When I doubt for the standards, I don't mean the time answer got posted. I did a right flag and the moderator declined it by mistake. Why I am banned, instead of him?

Comment: Again you're assuming that the moderator made a mistake, which isn't true. You flagged something as "not an answer", but it actually *is* an answer. It's not a *good* one, and you could have flagged as VLQ and been justified, but it is definitely an answer. Speaking more generally, if you've managed to get flag banned, I'd consider that strong evidence that you aren't sure of what flags to use when.

Comment: A flagging ban is normally handed out by getting *many* flags wrong, not just one.  Focusing only on the last one that tripped the limit doesn't help us help you getting better at it.  If you hope for a moderator to get banned then you certainly need more help understanding how SO works.  Well, you just got more time to think it over and review existing meta posts about it.

Comment: Thank you both. I think it is my own fault understanding what flags are and what they do.

Comment: Obligatory read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/294055

Comment: @ChrisHayes, but still I dont think if that is even a VLQ answer. I think that is just a comment, thus not an answer

Comment: @Trix it is really unclear to me what part of _"try this logging library"_ you think is not an answer to the question _"How to handle error logging"_. Try reading up on some of the previous discussions of the NAA flag. If an answer appears to answer _any_ question, the NAA flag does not apply. The NAA flag is for posts that are nonsense or new questions altogether.

Comment: The answer is perfectly on-topic and applicable to the question. The real problem here is that it's a bad and off-topic question, and you should have voted to close the question, rather than try to remove the answer(s).

Comment: What is the problem with my question that received 12 down votes? Is it that bad to ask questions about flags and their functionality? What is the problem here with a new guys? Every body from 2010 has asked so many silly questions and received hundreds of up votes. I don't think a question which attracted 100 views and 10 comments in a single day could be so bad deserving 12 down votes. Shame on Stack Overflow!

Comment: 1) lack of research 2) you might not realize this (am assuming you are not a native speaker), but the tone of your question and some of your comments (excluding the above) seems hostile.  3) assuming the problem isn't your own, 4) not recognizing that you have to have *many* declined flags to get a ban, and lastly 5) this suggests you have ignored every warning that your flags have not been received well and that you should review them for hints as to why.  Every single one of these will collect downvotes in Meta. But, no worries, it doesn't affect your rep.

Comment: @Will tnx for ur comment and kind explanation.1) that is true 2) yes I am not a native english speaker 3) No body asks a question in case he knows the problem is his own 4) I did not have many, I just had 5 and 5 is not many in my opinion 5) I did not ignore warnings as the stack did not warn me. I just came up with the Flag ban and nothing else happened before. By the way thanks for your time and comment. have fun

Comment: @Will as a final word, I don think that I have hostile activity, but the behaviour of aged users here is not kind enough to support new guys. Look at this very similar question to see what did they do to newbies: [Why was this spam-flag declined (no evidence to support it)?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267580/why-was-this-spam-flag-declined-no-evidence-to-support-it?rq=1) I don't see anything hostile in his question. he just asked a misunderstanding and see what did they do to him with 12 down votes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Note that it has received 9 up-votes!. I flagged it as:

It was also written in 2008. The site was younger back then, and the direction wasn't completely clear. It is clear however that multiple users found the advice in the answer useful, and the question has accumulated over 800 views since then.

In addition to that, in Shog9's famous [guide to identifying NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) he noted that:

> "Suggest me some tutorials where i can learn quick."
>
> Don't get me wrong, it's still a bad answer - but when the question is
>   kinda asking for bad answers this is to be expected. Close or flag the
>   question and move on - this is much more efficient than hanging around
>   to babysit it by deleting every crap answer that inevitably shows up.

So there are two reasons for why you shouldn't have flagged that:

1. It is 8 years old and accepted by the community
2. It is in response to a very broad and (and by today's standards inappropriate) vague question

As for retracting flags, that only works *before* they are handled. So if you misclick a flag and realize straight away, then sure, you can retract it. But after it's been reviewed, you're stuck with that.

As for your flag ban, you are only banned from flagging as long as 25% of your at least 10 flags in the past 7 days have been declined. That means your ban **will at the very worst last 1 week, and may even just be a day** [(source)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405).

Take this as a learning opportunity and move on.

Comment: This is pretty much why I declined it - it **is** an answer (albeit to a poor question) so I'd expect people to be taking action against the Q (which doesn't need a moderator), not incorrectly trying to label something that exactly answers the question as written NAA.

Comment: A silly question there and a link only answer there is good because is a 2008 stuff. A meaningful question here about flags real functionality deserves 12 down votes! By the way thanks for your time and explanations